# ADF Pipeline Schedule Information

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to get all pipeline schedule information from adf?
Checked in the azure monitor and trigger pipeline details. Could not find that information. How do I download / export all the schedule information

Thanks

Comment: No, we can't do that for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not support to view all pipeline schedule information now. We can only see the pipeline information that has been executed.